# How to color a dendrogram's labels according to defined groups? (in python)

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-learn, label, dendrogram

I would like to generate the labels of the plot in the same color of the groups. How should I do it?

Simple example test:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


mat = np.array([[1.0,  0.5,  0.0],
                [0.5,  1.0, -0.5],
                [1.0, -0.5,  0.5],
                [0.0,  0.5, -0.5]])

dist_mat = mat
linkage_matrix = linkage(dist_mat, "single")

plt.clf()

ddata = dendrogram(linkage_matrix, color_threshold=0.8)
```

The previous code generates this plot:

[image]

but I want the 0 and 2 index in blue and the 1 and 3 in red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


mat = np.array([[1.0, 0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 1.0, -0.5], [1.0, -0.5, 0.5], [0.0, 0.5, -0.5]])

dist_mat = mat
linkage_matrix = linkage(dist_mat, "single")

# plt.clf()

ddata = dendrogram(linkage_matrix, color_threshold=0.8)

# We get the color of leaves from the scipy dendogram docs
# The key is called "leaves_color_list". We iterate over the list of these colors and set colors for our leaves
# Please note that this parameter ("leaves_color_list") is different from the "color_list" which is the color of links
# (as shown in the picture)
# For the latest names of these parameters, please refer to scipy docs
# https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html
for leaf, leaf_color in zip(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), ddata["leaves_color_list"]):
    leaf.set_color(leaf_color)
plt.show()
```

The output is as shown below. The difference between parameters (`color_list` and `leaves_color_list`) have been highlighted to show the difference.
[image]

Comment: @JohanC noted the concern about explicit indices part! will fix asap. But how to note the earlier version, should I put a note of caution or rather put the source of the current keyword "leaves_color_list" from scipy so that the user can check for himself if it changes later?

Comment: @JohanC just checked the [scipy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html). The `color_list ` represents the colors for the links (three links in this image), while `leaves_color_list` is for the leaves (4 leaves in this image)

Comment: Thanks for checking. So, this is a completely new parameter.  It would be important to mention the current scipy version, so people testing with an older version and getting a "weird" error know they should upgrade.   See a.o. Codementor's [Stop using indices!](https://www.codementor.io/@philbest/stop-using-indices-woab0mh1t) about indices.

Comment: @JohanC updated the answer accordingly (1) removed explicit indexing, nice read (Stop reading indices!)  (2) added links to scipy doc and explained the parameter in the image as well, thanks for your suggestions!